# Python 3: How to import relative files instead of PyPi package

Tags: python, python-import

Is there a way to import relative files over PyPi packages which occupy the same namespace?

In the example below, `{package_name}` is both a relative folder and PyPi package name.

#### Directory Structure

```
{project_dir}/
    run.py
    {package_name}/
        __init__.py
        other.py
```

#### run.py

```py
from {package_name} import random_function
from {package_name}.other import other_function
```

If the PyPi package `{package_name}` is already installed with pip, it will make use of that PyPi package over the local directory named `{package_name}`.

Is there any way to reference the local directory instead? Is the best method to use `sys.path.append`?

Comment: Use a relative import: `from .{package_name} import random_function`?

Comment: @PeterWood I get the following error: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`